# SQLException during transaction end doesn't rollback as expected

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-transactions, rollback

I'm using Eclipselink and Spring transaction management. I want the program to insert two sets of master/detail records atomically, so that either both are inserted or neither.

Now, if my explicit validation fails either structure the code throws an exception and rollbackfor takes care of it. An error thrown during processing the second record rolls back the first.

Where things go pear-shaped is when there's a data error in processing the second transaction which results in an SQLException during the purge/commit process, In this case only the second record seems to be rolled back, the first is left in place.

I've tried various tweaks. The SQLException is normally fired during a find call during the process of validating the record, when that generates a flush(), but I've tried changing the EntityManger settings to turn that automatic flush off, and although a different exception is thrown at a different point in the program, the rollback still does the same thing.

I've tried requesting a new transaction for the update that throws the error, but the system says it can't give me a new transaction at that point.

I've tried doing a flush just before the end of the transaction in hopes of catching a DatabaseException and converting to the exception for the rollback.

Now, I can get more picky about validation, reducing the likelihood of data errors on the SQL, but I'd prefer to insure against missing something. I can fix the unit test that way, but there's sure to be other ways this can happen.

Oh, setting flush mode to "COMMIT" does make a difference. In that case *neither* record gets rolled back. Even if I catch the PersistenceException and throw my rollbackfor exception instead.

Comment: You mention two separate transactions, why would an exception in one affect the other?  What exactly happened when you called flush before the transaction end, and why couldn't you rollback both transactions at that point?  If you want true atomicity, you need this to occur in a single transaction, as once one commits, an error in the other can't rollback the first.

Comment: Sorry, my terminology was a bit woolly. I'm adding two records, each of which is an invoice headers with a variable number of lines and I want to ensure that I insert either both, or neither. These are supplied in a single REST call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I stumbled across a work around, just changing things at random. Flipped persistence.xml from JTA to RESOURCE_LOCAL. Now it seems fine.